# Making API call every 15 milliseconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I've got 3 functions, checkusername(username), checkemail(email), checkpassword(password). The API each one checks against has a rate limit and there has to be a delay of 15 milliseconds between each call. I have tried:

```
setTimeout(checkusername(username), 1500);
setTimeout(checkemail(email), 1500);
setTimeout(checkpassword(password), 1500);
```

That doesn't work. I've tried various other ways like increasing the delay by 1500 using a variable:

```
var delay = 1500;
checkusername(username);
if(delay == 1500) {
    delay = delay + 1500;
    checkemail(email);
}
else if(delay == 3000) {
    delay = delay + 1500;
    checkpassword(password);
}

console.log('Checks done!');
```

None of it works, still getting the code 429 (rate limit exceeded) come up in the console as per from HaveIbeenpwned API.

Either an answer using Javascript or jQuery or I could possibly try it in PHP if there is a solution that way?

By the way each function uses jQuery `$.ajax({})` call to the API.

EDIT:

```
function checkusername(username) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/'+username+'?includeUnverified=true',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var html = '<h4>Your username was found in the following hacked site breaches:</h4>';
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                    var breachName = data[i].Title;
                    var breachDesc = data[i].Description
                    html += '<h3><span class="label label-danger">'+breachName+'</span></h3>';
                    html += '<p>'+breachDesc+'</p>';
                    html += '<br>';
                }
                $('#results').append(html);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: 1500 is 1.5 seconds.  That's a *very* short time to expect an ajax call to consistently finish in.  Do you want the delay to be for each call, individually?  Or a delay between method 1 and 2, and 2 and 3?

Comment: Try Promises with timeout before resolving promise.

Comment: As per the HaveIbeenpwned API documentation, Troy has stated 15 millisecond delay between each API request. I need to fire each function but there has to be a delay between each one.

Comment: To best help you, it would be good to see the code you're using in the `checkemail` function, etc.

Comment: I don't know how to post code in the comment box but each one makes an Ajax call as per my original post then processes the JSON output that comes back from the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, here's a helper function that will return a Promise that will resolve in 15 milliseconds.

```
function delay15 () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) { setTimeout(resolve, 15) })
}
```

You'd need to write your `checkusername`, `checkemail`, & `checkpassword` functions to return Promises when the request has completed.

Example `checkusername` function (note the added `return` statement):

```
function checkusername(username) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/'+username+'?includeUnverified=true',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var html = '<h4>Your username was found in the following hacked site breaches:</h4>';
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                    var breachName = data[i].Title;
                    var breachDesc = data[i].Description
                    html += '<h3><span class="label label-danger">'+breachName+'</span></h3>';
                    html += '<p>'+breachDesc+'</p>';
                    html += '<br>';
                }
                $('#results').append(html);
            }
        });
    }
```

Then you'd write code something like this:

```
checkusername(username)
  .then(delay15)
  .then(function() { return checkemail(email) })
  .then(delay15)
  .then(function() { return checkpassword(password) })
```

---

Here's the same code in ES2015, which is shorter, though not as well-supported in browsers:

```
function delay15 () {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 15))
}

checkusername(username)
  .then(delay15)
  .then(() => checkemail(email))
  .then(delay15)
  .then(() => checkpassword(password))
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a go!

Comment: Now getting UnCaught TypeError: Cannot read property of 'then' of undefined

Comment: Not working in Chrome or Firefox. Keeps coming up with the error to do with .then()

Comment: @GeordieDave1980 Please update your question to contain the `checkusername` function

Comment: Updated it but for some reason the code has come out unformatted, I really do not know how to use this site very well.

Comment: Oh yeah should point out that the checkemail function looks exactly the same but instead of using the username variable it just uses the email variable. I'll handle the checkpassword function later on. I just need to try and get a solution sorted for this.

Comment: @GeordieDave1980 Edited to include `checkusername` example.

Comment: Still getting the rate limit exceeded, the delay isn't working. I do not understand why it isn't waiting the 15 milliseconds before then using the check email function which as I said is exactly like the check username function only using an email address.

Comment: Getting really fed up of this now, none of the delays are working. Tried setTimeout(), tried this new Promises thing, even found another site that had an example but that didn't work either. This is the major issue with rate limited APIs, something they're gonna have to fix and very soon!

Answer (score 1):

your setTimeout method is triggering all 3 requests essentially simultaneously, but 1.5 seconds after the setTimeout is invoked. try chaining your requests as promises or callbacks so you're not sending them all at the same time.

EDIT:
here's your example:

```
function checkUsername(u) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         //check username
        if (success) {return resolve();}
        else {return reject();}
    }
}

checkUsername('username').then(function() {checkNextThing()});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I've looked into Promises but I do not know how I'd do it. Can anyone give me an example of how I might do it please?

Comment: Obviously I can clean my code up later on, I just need to find a solution to this, it's not like I've not tried to sort it myself, I've tried various different ways using setTimeout or setInterval but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this sorted by now but on the off-chance that you do not then perhaps the following mighht be of use ~ seems to finally work OK! Rather than using jQuery ( I don't use it ) or the traditional `XMLHttpRequest` this relies upon the newer `Fetch` api which is based around the notion of `Promises`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Have I been pwned?</title>
        <script>
            var flags={
                capture:false,
                passive:true,
                once:false
            };

            /* Results from each request will be stored here */
            var data={};

            /* Whether or not to return FULL data as response */
            var truncate=false;

            /* Whether or not to include unverified results */
            var verified=false;

            /* A randomly chosen email address & password for testing */
            var username='dave@gmail.com';
            var email='andy@yahoo.com';
            var password='knickers';
            /* No idea who dave@gmail.com or andy@yahoo.com is btw */

            /* Request configuration */
            var config={
                'method':'get',
                'mode':'cors'
            };

            /* Error callback function */
            var evtError=function(err){
                console.info('oops: %s',err.message);
            };
            /* Time to wait */
            const t=1500;

            /* Promise to wait specified time */
            const wait = ms => new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, ms ) );

            function create( t, a, p ) {
                try{
                    var el = ( typeof( t )=='undefined' || t==null ) ? document.createElement( 'div' ) : document.createElement( t );
                    for( var x in a ) if( a.hasOwnProperty( x ) && x!=='innerHTML' ) el.setAttribute( x, a[ x ] );
                    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') ) el.innerHTML=a.innerHTML;
                    if( p!=null ) typeof( p )=='object' ? p.appendChild( el ) : document.getElementById( p ).appendChild( el );
                    return el;
                }catch(err){
                    console.warn('createNode: %s, %o, %o',t,a,p);
                }
            }

            function process( data ){
                if( typeof( data )=='object' ){
                    /* use the data */
                    console.info(data)

                    var div=document.getElementById('results');
                    var _username=data.username;
                    var _email=data.email;
                    var _pwd=data.password;

                    /* Process username pwnage */
                    create('h1',{innerHTML:'Username pwnage for: '+username },div );
                    for( var n in _username ){
                        if( typeof( _username[ n ] ) =='object' ){
                            var keys=Object.keys( _username[ n ] );
                            var values=Object.values( _username[ n ] );

                            keys.forEach(function(e,i,a){
                                create(null,{innerHTML:e+': '+values[i]},div);
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    /* Process email pwnage */
                    create('h1',{innerHTML:'Email pwnage for: '+email },div );
                    for( var n in _email ){
                        if( typeof( _email[ n ] ) =='object' ){
                            var keys=Object.keys( _email[ n ] );
                            var values=Object.values( _email[ n ] );

                            keys.forEach(function(e,i,a){
                                create(null,{innerHTML:e+': '+values[i]},div);
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    /* Finally - password pwnage */
                    create('h1',{innerHTML:'Password pwnage for: '+password },div );
                    create(null,{innerHTML:_pwd},div);
                }
            }

            function pwned( event ){
                var urls={
                    username:'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/'+encodeURIComponent( username )+'?truncateResponse='+truncate+'&includeUnverified='+verified,
                    email:'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/'+encodeURIComponent( email )+'?truncateResponse='+truncate+'&includeUnverified='+verified,
                    password:'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/pwnedpassword/'
                };

                /* Get the first url using "fetch" rather than XMLHttpRequest */
                fetch( urls.username, config ).then( function( res ){
                    if( res.ok ) return res.json();
                    if( res.status==404 )return 404;
                    throw new Error('Failed to check username');                    
                }).then( function( json ){
                    /* Add the response data to output object */
                    data.username=json;
                }).then( function(){
                    /* wait for pre-determined time */
                    return wait( t );
                }).then( function(){
                    /* Get the second url */
                    fetch( urls.email, config ).then(function( res ){
                        if( res.ok ) return res.json();
                        if( res.status==404 )return 404;
                        throw new Error('Failed to check email');
                    }).then( function( json ){
                        /* Add new response data to output object */
                        data.email=json;
                    }).then( function(){
                        /* Loiter, with intent, for a while... twiddle the thumbs etc */
                        return wait( t );
                    }).then( function(){

                        /* Finally get the last url - using POST as I found I was having issues with GET for some reason */
                        var headers=new Headers();
                            headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')

                        var config={
                            'mode':'cors',
                            'method':'post',
                            'body':'Password='+encodeURIComponent( password ),
                            'headers':headers
                        };

                        fetch( urls.password, config ).then( function( res ){
                            if( res.ok ) return res.json();
                            if( res.status==404 )return 404;
                            throw new Error('Failed to check password');
                        }).then( function(status){
                            /* And store the response */
                            data.password=status==200 ? 'pwned' : 'ok';
                            return status;
                        }).then(function(status){
                            return data;
                        }).then( function( data ){
                            /* play with the data */
                            process.call( this, data );
                        }).catch( evtError );
                    }).catch( evtError );
                }).catch( evtError );
            }



            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                var bttn=document.querySelector('input[type="button"][name="pwnage"]');
                bttn.onclick=pwned;
            },flags);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='button' name='pwnage' value='Check pwnage' />
            <div id='results'></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I found that it was possible to lower the timeout period to 1000ms on occasion but seemed a little flaky. The implementation of the method chaining could probably be improved upon but it was my first attempt at a really complicated usage of `fetch`

Doing further testing lead me to try some of my own email addresses as I'd not been on [have I been pwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) for quite a while - not a happy bunny after finding a couple had been pwned :(